# How to get user statistics for charts and graphs?

Tags: views, 8, entities, nodes

**Q: How can I get statistics of specific user fields?**

I want to display a chart using the answers users have provided in their profile. It should appear on the landing page.

Something like

- Age
- favorite color
- month of registration

I have tried to get data from public fields but I can't figure out how to do so with field data that is not visible to unregistered users.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I this question more, "How do I allow anonymous site visitors to see aggregated private data?"

Comment: If you are not talking about aggregating the data, can you just change the permissions on the fields to allow anonymous users to view it? Go to http://yoursite.com/admin/people/permissions